# Is there any function in Haskell that applies a two argument function to two lists, element by element?

Tags: haskell

I just wanted to multiply two lists element by element, so I'd pass (*) as the first argument to that function:

```
apply :: Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
apply f xs ys = [f (xs !! i) (ys !! i) | i <- [0..(length xs - 1)]]
```

I may be asking a silly question, but I actually googled a lot for it and just couldn't find. Thank you, guys!

Comment: Next time you could use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), the Haskell API search engine. The function that you are looking for is [zipWith](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=zipWith).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
> :t zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
> zipWith (*) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
[4,10,18]
```

It's the eighth result provided by [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[a]) when queried with your type

```
(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Moreover, when you need to implement your own function, use `list !! index` only as a last resort, since it usually leads to a bad performance, having a cost of `O(index)`. Similarly, `length` should be used only when necessary, since it needs to scan the whole list.

In the `zipWith` case, you can avoid both and proceed recursively in a natural way: it is roughly implemented as

```
zipWith _ []     _      = []
zipWith _ _      []     = []
zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith f xs ys
```

Note that this will only recurse as much as needed to reach the end of the shortest list. The remaining part of the longer list will be discarded.

Comment: You shouldn't need the import since `zipWith` is included with the Prelude.

Comment: [It's the first result on hoogle with the more general type signature](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[b]+-%3E+[c])

Comment: @Eric Thanks -- simplified.

Comment: @bheklilr True. I used the one provided by the OP since realizing the generalization can be a non trivial step for a beginner, I think.

Comment: You might want to specifically mention the behavior when one list is longer than another, since the phrasing of the original question doesn't show an awareness of this issue. (The code he wrote will throw an exception if the first list is longer than the second).